# Cell Calculation in CSV are not right. Showing wrong number. Get Error

Tags: powershell, sum, calculated-columns, calculated-field

I am trying to get one cell to output a calculation of lines of another cell. Some cells are calculated wrong.

Here is my sample data:

> ```
>      Total Devices   Vulnerability Description      Comments
> Row1      3             Plugin:1234                 Host1.Domain
>                         Device Affected:            Host4.Domain
>                         Host1.Domain                Host5.Domain
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
> Row2       12           Plugin:5678                 Host2.Domain
>                         Device Affected:            Host3.Domain
>                         Host2.Domain
> ```

It should be

> ```
>      Total Devices   Vulnerability Description      Comments
> Row1      3             Plugin:1234                 Host1.Domain
>                         Device Affected:            Host4.Domain
>                         Host1.Domain                Host5.Domain
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
> Row2       1           Plugin:5678                 Host2.Domain
>                         Device Affected:           
>                         Host2.Domain
> ```

My code:

> # Define the host names we want to remove
>       $PendingRemoval = "Host3.Domain","Host6.Domain"

```
# Import the original data set
$Data = Import-Csv .\Old.csv

for($i = 0; $i -lt $data.Count; $i++)
{
    # Grab all hostnames from the comments field
    $HostNames = $Data[$i].Comments -split "`r?`n"

    #Set Vulnerability Column Variable
    [string]$VulnerabilityDesc = $Data[$i].'Vulnerability Description'   

    #Remove the Hostnames from Vulnerability Cells
    foreach ($HostName in $HostNames) {
    $VulnerabilityDesc = $VulnerabilityDesc.Replace($HostName, "")
    }
    $VulnerabilityDesc = $VulnerabilityDesc.Replace("Devices Affected", "")
    $VulnerabilityDesc = $VulnerabilityDesc.TrimEnd()
    $Data[$i].'Vulnerability Description' = $VulnerabilityDes

    # Filter out unwanted ones
    $HostNames = $HostNames |Where-Object {$_ -notin $PendingRemoval}

    # Update original row
    $Data[$i].Comments = $HostNames -join [System.Environment]::NewLine
    $Data[$i].'Total Devices' = $HostNames.Length
}

# Export it to same csv
$Data | Export-Csv .\New.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, it looks like your `Import-CSV` needs a `-delimiter '\t'` to work properly.

Where exactly do you call a `.replace`?

Comment: im sorry I took that part out. That actually is another part of my code where I am trying to replace a hostname with a blank. I will edit it to include that part

Comment: Ok, with that we can work. The problem seems to be in `$hostnames`. Have you checked its content? maybe your split does not work as excepted. How does the data look when you call `$Data[$i].Comments `?

Comment: it says 
    `$Data[$i].Comments=Host1.Domain
Host4.Domain
Host5.Domain`

Comment: The error did go away but I get e new error `Exception setting "Total Devices": "The property 'Total Devices' cannot be 
found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set."
At C:\Users\J54121\Desktop\Scripts\test.ps1:53 char:5
+     $Data[$i].'Total Devices= $HostNames.Length`

Comment: Can you post the complete output of `$Data` in your question as a code-section?

Comment: The error went away... turns out I had a spelling error somewhere. My only issue now is the Total Devices calculation is not correct. I will update the code with what I have.

Comment: What numbers are wrong? The only thing that comes in my mind is `$Data[$i].'Total Devices' = $HostNames.Length` 
I guess you meant `$Data[$i].'Total Devices' = $HostNames.count`

Comment: the total hosts it is calculating is wrong. I tried `count` but that displays wrong numbers as well

Comment: Just for clarification: The amount of machines listed in the comment-section reduced by the entries of $PendingRevoval shall be displayed as 'total hosts'?

Comment: In which way are the numbers not correct? Can you give an example?

Comment: well if I run the code as is. The total it displays under Total devices for the number of hosts in comments for the first set is 3 and for the second set is 12 but when I run the code there is only 1 host in that cell. I edited my question.

Comment: When you stop your script at line "Update original row" while $i = 1: how is $hostnames looking? Its supposed to be like `$hostname = "Host2.Domain"`. Correct? and how does it look when you pause and call the variable?

Comment: Have you tried with splitting via ' ' instead of  '`r?`n'?

Comment: That is correct. The variable is Host2.Domain while `$i = 1` but its Host1.Domain Host4.Domain Host5.Domain while `$i = 0`. I did... That made both numbers higher

Comment: What is the output of $hostnames.count while i=1? Maybe we'll find the error that way

Comment: `$Hostnames = Host2.Domain, Host3.Domain` with ' ' and `$Hostnames=Host2.Domain` with the `"`r?`n"`... Thank you so much for trying to help me.

Comment: When I get right, the output is correct when splitting with r?n. So should $hostnames.count be 1. 
Write back the output of $hostnames.count if this is not true

Comment: That's correct it should be one, but the output in "Total Devices" does not output 1 with count. I. believe it was 45.